# Cannot save a plotly figure as png due to kaleido error

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, plotly, jupyter, kaleido

I keep getting the following error:

```
ValueError: Failed to start Kaleido subprocess. Error stream:

/home/<username>/Projects/Workspace 1/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/kaleido/executable/kaleido: line 9: cd: too many arguments
/home/<username>/Projects/Workspace 1/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/kaleido/executable/kaleido: line 10: ./bin/kaleido: No such file or directory
```

I am using VS Code on arch linux. Note that I use a jupyter notebook virtual kernel.

Comment: From the path as part of your answer, I see you are using `venv`. The first link I got when searching `"kaleido: No such file or directory"`,which was at the very end of your posted error, was to [this issue 'Static Image Export Fails If Kaleido is Installed in a virtualenv with Spaces in the Path'](https://github.com/plotly/Kaleido/issues/78). dgoppenheimer and several folks after suggest solutions. Keep in mind that dgoppenheimer was referencing Google Colab and so used methods compatible with there. However, if you are using modern Jupyter, you want to use the magic symbol variations. ....

Comment: <continued> Not the exclamation version of commands that involve `pip` or `conda`. Always use `%pip` or `%conda` when inside an modern Jupyter notebook in true Jupyter. Unfortunately, Google Colab is based on a branch off an older version of Jupyter and so remains un-updated at this time and doesn't match current best practices in the Jupyter ecosystem. TLDR; : Try `%conda install -c conda-forge python-kaleido` if you are using Anaconda/conda or , if not, try things like `%pip uninstall kaleido` and `%pip install kaleido`, and do similarly for other suggested solutions.

Comment: I also note this issue is similar to what you report: [Using plotly in service file](https://github.com/plotly/Kaleido/issues/128). However, I think the other is a better match because of `.venv` being involved in your path. But since it references other things, you or others encountering this may want to know about that report, too.

Comment: I tried again by renaming all folders and files in the path to exclude the spaces and creating a new venv. This time I get the error `ValueError: Failed to start Kaleido subprocess. Error stream:

/home/<username>/Projects/Workspace_1/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/kaleido/executable/kaleido: line 10:  5396 Segmentation fault      ./bin/kaleido $@`

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't find any other advice for that. That issue thread seemed like it was promising. I don't know what else to suggest.

Answer (score 0):

I found this why it happens:

1. kaleido requires more system memory as it starts up about twice as fast as **orca**. So, it requires more resources while execution.
   2 If you want a quick start to export static image you can use "matplotlib" which can function as same as plotly.kaleido(but, kaleido is more efficient to visualize the data).
2. you can check with this https://github.com/plotly/Kaleido/blob/master/README.md for more info.